# how can I add package name that function is associated with to a source code what package

Tags: r, package

I have a complicated source code that makes use of several packages.Is there a way to get a list of the function and the package it associated with?
for example in my code:

```
uploaded.data.Factors.Included <- reactive({
      inFile <- input$datafile
      if (is.null(inFile)) {return(NULL)}
      SPY <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header, sep = input$sep, quote = "")
```

How can I get somthing like :

```
uploaded.data.Factors.Included <- shiny::reactive({
          inFile <- input$datafile
          if (is.null(inFile)) {return(NULL)}
          SPY <- base:: read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header, sep = input$sep, quote = "")
```

Or as a list:

```
Shiny reactive
Base read.csv
```

Comment: This works for packages other than base (which is imported implicitly): Do not import these functions in your NAMESPACE file. Then run `Rcmd check --as-cran`. It should give you notes like `gasfluxes: no visible global function definition for 'png'
Undefined global functions or variables:
  png
Consider adding
  importFrom("grDevices", "png")
to your NAMESPACE file.` (example from one of my packages).

Comment: So what is the right way to do it?

Comment: Hello @Roland, I guess I'm missing something : what does it mean "Consider adding importFrom("grDevices", "png") to your NAMESPACE file" ?

Comment: That's part of the output you get from running the checks (and basically what I understood to be what you need).

Comment: How can I incorporate it into my code ?

Comment: I have no idea what exactly you want to achieve and why you would want that. Possibly you are not even creating a package?

Comment: I'm not creating a package, I'm looking for a way to add package name before the function that is associated with inside the source code in order to understand what function belongs to what package in a rather complicated and long code.

Comment: Why do you need that? You could transform your code into a package and do what I described above. Otherwise, I don't know an easy way. For a single function you could use `getAnywhere` to find its package.

Comment: Thank you, I'll follow your direction.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could check the namespace of the package? I mean literally check the file NAMESPACE. It will contain all the exported functions of that package.

Comment: I would like to get the active function per package as a list or inside the code as i have about 8 packages and about 2k rows code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your question is different than I thought.

You have a script (not a package) that calls different functions from several packages. So:

`library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
select(df, var1, var2, var5)  # part of dplyr
gather(data, key, value)   # part of tidyr`

And you would like to know to which package the functions belong?
But not only that , but a list of all the functions in use in the script, with their package.  I don't know a automated way to do that.

An idea (without code):

1. recognize all the function calls within the script
2. recognize the library calls (or require, if you must)
3. download all namespaces from these libraries
4. match 1 to 3